# Broadcast receiver registered in manifest not getting called in Android Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have registered following `receiver` which is not getting called in Android Oreo but works on lower version devices.

```
<receiver
     android:name=".common.receiver.ConsultReceiver"
     android:exported="false">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="APP_STARTED" />
            <action android:name="APP_STARTED_FROM_ORGANIC" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 11):

In general, [you cannot use an implicit `Intent` (e.g., one with just an action string) for a broadcast on Android 8.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts).

Your `<receiver>` is not exported. This suggests one of three things:

1. You are using this with a `PendingIntent`, such as for a `Notification`. If so, get rid of the `<intent-filter>` and use an explicit `Intent` (`new Intent(this, ConsultReceiver.class)`) as part of creating your `PendingIntent` that points to this receiver.
2. You are using this as part of some IPC between multiple app processes in your app. In that case, also use an explicit `Intent`.
3. You are using this receiver purely within one process within your app. In that case, get rid of the `<receiver>` and use something else (`LocalBroadcastManager`, an event bus, RxJava, `LiveData`, etc.).

Comment: But it is not implicit broadcast receiver

Comment: @Ragini: A *receiver* is neither implicit nor explicit. An `Intent` is implicit or explicit. An explicit `Intent` identifies the Java class of the component; an implicit `Intent` does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare for explicit intent , dont we need to `register` the receiver ?? (if we remove `<intent-filter>` from manifest)

Comment: @SantanuSur: You need a `<receiver>` element. It does not need an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: just the `<receiver>` in the manifest and `explicit intent` to call the receiver is enough  ryt (in 8.0+) ?? And then for `push notification` if i want to launch an `explicit intent` to an actvity from that particular `receiver` wil also work in all versions of android ryt ?? (just to make my concept clear) @CommonsWare

Comment: @SantanuSur: I am not aware that FCM changes anything regarding how explicit `Intents` work, if that is what you are asking. Nothing changed with respect to starting activities in Android 8.x.

Comment: Can we start an `explicit intent` to an activity directly from FCM ( `onMessageReceived` ) or do we need to broadcast it to a receiver and from the receiver we need to start the activity ...( indirectly ) OR  `implicit intent directly to an activity` is still allowed in `8.x` ? ( from `onMessageReceived` )

Comment: **Nothing changed with respect to starting activities in Android 8.x** got it thanks :) @CommonsWare ( just the receiver (call should be through explicit intent) is all that changed in `8.x` )

Comment: @SantanuSur: correct. Note that starting an activity from a push message may not make the user happy, if that interrupts what they are doing. Consider raising a notification instead.

Comment: Away from Android programming for a while, very late to the party and this happened :( I think I need to update some of my apps now. 1. As for the Implicit Intents, is the same true for something like Intent.ACTION_CALL too? 2. Will be static registration in AndroidManifest.xml still valid such as <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>?

Comment: @Jenix: "As for the Implicit Intents, is the same true for something like Intent.ACTION_CALL too?" -- that is not used for broadcasts. "Will be static registration in AndroidManifest.xml still valid such as <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>?" -- only if the action is on [the whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` happens to be on the whitelist, but most actions are not.

Comment: Oh, you said "you cannot use an implicit Intent (e.g., one with just an action string) for a *broadcast*", not an activity, I see! Now I know what to do. Thanks as always! :)

Answer (score 6):

If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

Comment: But it is not implicit broadcast receiver

Answer (score 3):

In Android 8.0 and above, use the following code to check when some app is installed or uninstalled.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val receiver = YourBroadcastReceiverClass()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val filter = IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
        filter.addDataScheme("package")

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    }

    override fun onDestory() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Restrict the `Intent` to your package with [setPackage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)).

Comment: is this enough?