# Oreo - Not able to register Receiver onResume

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle, android-broadcastreceiver, onresume

I am getting error while unregistering the receiver.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: PackageName$2@fb33e41
01-11 15:17:47.188 19883-19883/PackageName W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1193)
01-11 15:17:47.188 19883-19883/PackageName W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1449)
01-11 15:17:47.188 19883-19883/PackageName W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:645)
```

However I am registering the receiver on onResume

```
try {
            mReceiver_video = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   // work
                }};

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        registerReceiver(mReceiver_video, intentFilterVideo);
```

I am only getting the issue only in version 8.0 and above devices.
Its working fine on below version.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593120/3338583). He has perfectly answered your question

Comment: Please post the code which shows the `unregisterReceiver` call.

Comment: unregisterReceiver(mReceiver_video);

Comment: using the above code on onActivityResult (where required) and on onDestroy()