# Failed to fire broadcast receiver in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-syncadapter, android-8.1-oreo

Using **SyncAdapter** and **AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter**
https://riptutorial.com/android/example/32303/sync-adapter-with-every-min-requesting-value-from-server-
I have registered receiver in manifest and from SyncAdapter broadcast register its working fine before Oreo but in Oreo, broadcast receiver failed to fire.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();   
             intent.setAction("package.qa.ACTION_SYNC");
            intent.putExtra("OUTBOX_ID", outboxId);
            intent.putExtra("JSON_RESPONSE", jsonResponse);
            intent.putExtra("TRANS_TYPE", transaction);
            getContext().sendBroadcast();
```

Comment: Add component name in intent. Can you look into local broadcast manager?

Comment: already tried its not working in Oreo ... component name is only working when trying to startService from activity Do u have any sample example to execute componentName in Oreo from any background Service/Sync Adapter ?